# Random Number Displays 2 numbers when it should only display one

Tags: c#

I am playin around with generating random numbers, and I can get them to generate, although my console.writeline(randomList[i]); seems to loop twice and then displays both results, it should only display one value per loop, and the user should have to hit any-key to get the next result. Can someone give a little insight on this? Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GenerateRandomNumbers();
    }
    private static void GenerateRandomNumbers()
    {
        //Initialize an array 
        int[] randomList = new int[1000];
        //Initialize an instance of random class 
        Random rnd = new Random();
        // integer variable 
        int counter = 0;
            while (counter < 1000)
            {
                //store random num  
                int random = rnd.Next(1, 1001);

                if (Array.IndexOf(randomList, random) <= 0)
                {
                    //store random number into Array 
                    randomList[counter] = random;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        //output elements in Array 
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(randomList[i]);
            Console.Read();
        }
        //output number of elements in Array 
       // Console.WriteLine(counter);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Some keys generate two characters in rapid succession, which could cause `Console.Read()` to return twice quickly.

Comment: As for your random number generation, you seem to be generating numbers from 1 to 1000 to fill 1000 slots in an array, checking for collisions along the way. You'll find that your chances of collision rise to near 100% with each successive addition. A better approach would be to simply create the 1000 values beforehand and then perform a random shuffle. No collisions, better performance. Look into algorithms such as Fisher-Yates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the Console.ReadLine() in the loop instead of the Console.Read()